# How do I solve $\lim_{p\to\infty}\left(\frac{S_{p}}{S_{p-1}}-\frac{S_{p-1}}{S_{p-2}}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, summation

## The Problem

---

For reference,

$$S_p=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^{p}}{2^n}$$

This sequence is found on the OEIS as A000629 (https://oeis.org/A000629). It can be easily shown that,

$$S_p-1=\binom{p}{1}S_{p-1}+\binom{p}{2}S_{p-2}+\ldots+\binom{p}{p-1}S_{1}+\binom{p}{p}S_0$$

This formula is already well known and I have already proven it. Then I had proven the following:

$$\frac{S_p}{S_{p-1}}\sim Cp$$ where $C$ is some non-zero constant.

Now I went on to trying to find a $C$ that would best approximate this series because then an explicit formula would result. So this is,

$$C=\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}=\frac{\frac{S_p}{S_{p-1}}-\frac{S_{p-1}}{S_{p-2}}}{p-(p-1)}=\frac{S_p}{S_{p-1}}-\frac{S_{p-1}}{S_{p-2}}$$ because $Cp$ approaches $\frac{S_p}{S_{p-1}}$ as $p\to\infty$ I add the limit and here is where my problem arises. That is,

$$\lim_{p\to\infty}\left(\frac{S_{p}}{S_{p-1}}-\frac{S_{p-1}}{S_{p-2}}\right)$$

I can safely say that this limit will most likely go to $\frac{1}{\ln 2}$ as this is what occurs on Desmos and Wolfram when plotted; it is also the $C$ that can be seen on the OEIS that others have found. However when proving what the limit tends to, it wouldn't be sound to say "It looks like it does, so it does".

## My Attempts

---

### Using the Series Definition

$$\lim_{p\to\infty}\left(\frac{S_{p}}{S_{p-1}}-\frac{S_{p-1}}{S_{p-2}}\right)=\lim_{p\to\infty}\left(\frac{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^{p}}{2^n}}{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^{p-1}}{2^n}}-\frac{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^{p-1}}{2^n}}{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^{p-2}}{2^n}}\right)$$

This of course does not look fun to solve and I figured it might have been a waste of my time but I attempted to make something of it anyways. I combined fractions,

$$\lim_{p\to\infty}\left(\frac{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^{p}}{2^n}}{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^{p-1}}{2^n}}-\frac{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^{p-1}}{2^n}}{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^{p-2}}{2^n}}\right)=\lim_{p\to\infty}\left(\frac{\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^{p}}{2^n}\right)\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^{p-2}}{2^n}\right)-\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^{p-1}}{2^n}\right)^2}{\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^{p-1}}{2^n}\right)\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^{p-2}}{2^n}\right)}\right)$$

This still unfortunately got me nowhere as I didn't know how to interpret nor simplify the multiplied sums.

### Using the Recursive Definition

---

I have tried using the recursive definition of the limit but still that doesn't get me anything of interest.

$$C=\lim_{p\to\infty}\left(\frac{\binom{p}{1}S_{p-1}+\ldots+\binom{p}{p}S_{0}+1}{\binom{p}{2}S_{p-2}+\ldots+\binom{p}{p}S_{0}+1}-\frac{\binom{p}{2}S_{p-2}+\ldots+\binom{p}{p}S_{0}+1}{\binom{p}{3}S_{p-3}+\ldots+\binom{p}{p}S_{0}+1}\right)$$

Then I know that the 1s become negligible as $p\to\infty$ then I also used that $\binom{n}{k}\sim\frac{n^k}{k!}$

$$C=\lim_{p\to\infty}\left(\frac{\frac{p^1}{1!}S_{p-1}+\ldots+\frac{p^p}{p!}S_{0}}{\frac{p^2}{2!}S_{p-2}+\ldots+\frac{p^p}{p!}S_{0}}-\frac{\frac{p^2}{2!}S_{p-2}+\ldots+\frac{p^p}{p!}S_{0}}{\frac{p^3}{3!}S_{p-3}+\ldots+\frac{p^p}{p!}S_{0}}\right)=\lim_{p\to\infty}\left(\frac{\frac{p^1}{1!}S_{p-1}}{\frac{p^2}{2!}S_{p-2}+\ldots+\frac{p^p}{p!}S_{0}}-\frac{\frac{p^2}{2!}S_{p-2}}{\frac{p^3}{3!}S_{p-3}+\ldots+\frac{p^p}{p!}S_{0}}\right)$$

This is where I am know and still I have no clue how to proceed with this limit. If anyone has any ideas at all on where to begin that would be excellent. Thanks!

Comment: It might be useful to observe that (more or less by definition) the sum is given by the value of a polylogarithm function: $S_p = \operatorname{Li}_{-p}\left(\frac12\right)$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm

Comment: @TravisWillse I apologize if I'm not responding correctly, new to the Stack Exchange. I have seen that and I figured it could be something of interest for sure.

$$\lim_{p\to\infty}\left(\frac{\operatorname{Li}_{-p}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\operatorname{Li}_{-p-1}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}-\frac{\operatorname{Li}_{-p-1}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\operatorname{Li}_{-p-2}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}\right)$$

I'm not sure that would be much easier to evaluate? Unless you have any ideas you'd be willing to share :)

Comment: Yes, comments are exactly the right place for this sort of discussion. I don't know enough enough about the asymptotics of $\operatorname{Li}_s$ to say more, but the polylogarithms are well studied and so probably something useful is known. Welcome to math.se, by the way.

Comment: @TravisWillse I see, thank you very much. I'll try to see if anything of notable interest catches my eye while looking at polylogs!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your initial assumption is correct that the limit is $ \frac{1}{\ln(2)}$. We can begin to prove it by recognizing that you sum is actually just twice the [ordered bell numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_Bell_number) that have a definition as follows.
$$
S_p = 2a_p = \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{n^p}{2^{p}}
$$
Another formula for the ordered bell numbers is as follows.
$$
S_p = 2a_p = p! \sum^{\infty}_{k = -\infty} \frac{1}{(\ln(2)+2\pi ik)^{p+1}}
$$
From here we can use two arguments for why...
$$
\lim_{p \to \infty} S_p = \frac{p!}{\ln^{p+1}(2)}
$$
The first is very hand wavy and goes as folows. If p is very large then the terms with a sizable k value will be effectively zero and hence if the only contributing term is when k is zero. This gives you the above. The less hand wavy argument is as follows.

We can then perform some transformations.
$$
\frac{p!}{(2\pi i)^{p+1}} \sum^{\infty}_{k = -\infty} \frac{1}{\left(\frac{\ln(2)}{2\pi i} + k\right)^{p+1}}
$$
$$
\frac{p!}{(2\pi i)^{p+1}} \left( \sum^{\infty}_{k = 0} \frac{1}{\left(\frac{\ln(2)}{2\pi i} + k\right)^{p+1}} + (-1)^{p+1}\sum^{\infty}_{k = 0} \frac{1}{\left(-\frac{\ln(2)}{2\pi i} + k\right)^{p+1}} - \left( \frac{\ln(2)}{2\pi i}\right)^{p+1}  \right)
$$
$$
\frac{p!}{(2\pi i)^{p+1}} \left( \zeta \left(p+1, \frac{\ln(2)}{2\pi i}\right) + (-1)^{p+1}\zeta\left(p+1, -\frac{\ln(2)}{2\pi i}\right) - \left( \frac{\ln(2)}{2\pi i}\right)^{p+1}  \right)
$$
Where $\zeta(s,a)$ is the [Hurowitz-Zeta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_zeta_function) function. The Hurowitz-Zeta function obeys the following property.
$$
\zeta(s,ia) + \zeta(s,-ia) = 2\Re [\zeta(s,ia)] \ , \ \zeta(s,ia) - \zeta(s,-ia) = 2i\Im [\zeta(s,ia)]
$$
Hence, we have to different behaviors for even $p$ and odd $p$ which I will write as $2p$ and $2p+1$ respectively.
$$
-\frac{(2p)!}{\ln^{2p+1}(2)} + \frac{(-1)^{p}(2p)!}{\pi^{2p+1}4^p} \Im \left[ \zeta \left(2p+1, \frac{\ln(2)}{2\pi i}\right) \right]
$$
$$
-\frac{(2p+1)!}{\ln^{2p+2}(2)} + \frac{(-1)^{p+1}(2p+1)!}{\pi^{2p+2}2^{2p+1}} \Re \left[ \zeta \left(2p+2, \frac{\ln(2)}{2\pi i}\right) \right]
$$
All this was done to get a completely real representation. We can then consider what happens as $p \to \infty$.
$$
\lim_{s \to \infty} \zeta (s,a) = a^{-s}
$$
Hence...
$$
\lim_{p \to \infty} \Im \left[ \zeta \left(2p+1, \frac{\ln(2)}{2\pi i}\right) \right] = (-1)^{p} \left( \frac{2\pi}{\ln(2)} \right)^{2p+1}
$$
$$
\lim_{p \to \infty} \Re \left[ \zeta \left(2p+2, \frac{\ln(2)}{2\pi i}\right) \right] = (-1)^{p+1} \left( \frac{2\pi}{\ln(2)} \right)^{2p+2}
$$
Which gives us the same representation for even $p$ and odd $p$ when added together with the other term hence.
$$
\lim_{p \to \infty} S_{p} = \frac{p!}{\ln^{p+1}(2)}
$$
This gives us the same result. We can then use this in the limit.
$$
\lim_{p \to \infty} \frac{S_{p}}{S_{p-1}} - \frac{S_{p-1}}{S_{p-2}}
$$
$$
\lim_{p \to \infty} \frac{p!}{\ln^{p+1}(2)} \frac{\ln^{p}(2)}{(p-1)!} - \frac{(p-1)!}{\ln^{p}(2)} \frac{\ln^{p-1}(2)}{(p-2)!}
$$
$$
\lim_{p \to \infty} \frac{p}{ln(2)}-\frac{p-1}{\ln(2)} = \frac{1}{\ln(2)}
$$
QED

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is a great answer, thank you so much for providing such a detailed response! I will definitely be looking into the ordered bell numbers and Hurwitz Zeta function and where these formulae all came from. Wish you good health :)